# Chrome extension refresh vs opened in a new window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that runs in its own pop-up window.

Is there any way to detect if that pop-up window (extension window) was refreshed or the user opened a new window of this extension?

Comment: Try using sessionStorage: check if it contains foo - it'll be a refresh, otherwise store it - it'll be a new start.

Comment: @wOxxOm that would actually work, thanks for the comment. However, I realized that I don't need to know if the window was refreshed or not to solve the problem I was having.